# Javascript namespace - exchange of variable between functions

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I know I am doing something egregiously wrong in using the namespaces. I am posting this question after researching a ton in the net / google searches. Still can’t find what I am doing wrong. Can you please help me out?
This is what I have

**Javascript**

Javascript file1

```
(function (js_namspace1, $, undefined) {
    js_namespace1.n1function1 = function(){

      var return_obj = {
         return_function_to_call: “n1function_name2”
         return_function_to_call_namespace: “js_namespace1”
       }
      js_namespace2.n2function1(return_obj)
    }
    Js_namespace1.n1function_name2 =function(list_of_names){
        Js_namespace1.list_of_names = list_of_names
        // do some processing to js_namespace1. list_of_names
    }
}
(window. js_namspace1 = window. js_namspace1|| {}, jQuery ));
```

Javascript file2

```
(function (js_namspace2, $, undefined) {
    js_namespace2.n2function1(return_obj) = function(return_obj){
    js_namespace2.return_function_to_call =     return_obj.return_function_to_call
    js_namespace2.return_function_to_call_namespace = return_obj.  .return_function_to_call_namespace

    // do some processing
    Js_namespace2.list_of_names = []
    Js_namespace2. list_of_names.push(value_name)
    window[js_namespace2.return_function_to_call_namespace][js_namespace2.return_function_to_call]( Js_namespace2.list_of_names);
  }
}
(window. js_namspace2 = window. js_namspace2|| {}, jQuery ));
```

**Html**

From html file1 call js_namespace1.n1function1 based on end user clicking a field

// `js_namespace1.n1function1` calls `js_namespace2.n2function1` and displays another html file2

// In html file2 process the data (collect value of names) and then call the return function `Js_namespace1.n1function_name2`

In `Js_namespace1.n1function_name2`, process `Js_namespace1.list_of_names(array)`, but when I do this, it also changes in `Js_namespace2.list_of_names`

For example when I do 
`Js_namespace1.n1function_name2.push(add_another_name)`, and then call `js_namespace1.n1function1`  (which in turn calls `js_namespace2.n2function1`).  `Js_namespace2.list_of_names` contains the value of `add_another_name`.

Please note that when `js_namespace2.n2function1` is called from `js_namespace1.n1function1` the array is not passed as parameter.

**My expectation** was when `js_namespace1.n1function1` calls `js_namespace2.n2function1` it **would not update** `Js_namespace2.list_of_names` with the `add_another_name`.

Can you please explain what is happening? most importantly point out any mistakes that I should be avoiding in this design (namespace, exchange of parameters between function calls). Am I using the namespace correctly in javascript – any best practices to recommend?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: First thing to do is check your developer console. You've got lots of typos in your code (`Var` instead of `var` etc).

Comment: Please write your code in an editor, not a word processor. Spelling and casing matters in programming. Use `"…"` not `“…”`, use `js_namespace…` not `Js_namespace…`. Also some indentation would help readability a lot.

Comment: See also [Copying array by value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/1048572) for a solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](https://www.thinkful.com/learn/javascript-best-practices-1/) from a quick Google search on best practices for JS. There are different schools of thought out there (eg. [use of terminating semicolons](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/)), but use of a some kind of linter might help you figure out typos, case sensitivity, and unintended whitespace in the code if you can't notice for yourself. Below is your code with some fixes:

```
(function (js_namespace1, $, undefined) {

    js_namespace1.n1function1 = function(){

      var return_obj = {
         return_function_to_call: "n1function_name2",
         return_function_to_call_namespace: "js_namespace1"
       };
      js_namespace2.n2function1(return_obj)
    };
    js_namespace1.n1function_name2 =function(list_of_names){
        js_namespace1.list_of_names = list_of_names;
        console.log(js_namespace1.list_of_names); // ["some_name"]
    };
}
(js_namespace1 = window.js_namespace1 || {}, jQuery));

(function (js_namespace2, $, undefined) {
    js_namespace2.n2function1 = function(return_obj){
    js_namespace2.return_function_to_call =  return_obj.return_function_to_call;
    js_namespace2.return_function_to_call_namespace = return_obj.return_function_to_call_namespace;

    // do some processing
    js_namespace2.list_of_names = [];
    js_namespace2.list_of_names.push("some_name");
    window[js_namespace2.return_function_to_call_namespace][js_namespace2.return_function_to_call]( js_namespace2.list_of_names);
  };
}
(js_namespace2 = window.js_namespace2 || {}, jQuery));
js_namespace1.n1function1();
```

Some points about your code and my fixes:

- You used case sensitive names like `js_namespace2` for `Js_namespace2`.
- Your syntax here is incorrect `js_namespace2.n2function1(return_obj) = function(return_obj)`.
- And here: `return_obj.  .return_function_to_call_namespace` and others.
- `value_name` is not defined

I tested the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g7qb4c9f/1/) and see expected behavior.